# How to throw exception only in debug?

Tags: c#

Suppose I want throw exception only when I use the debug mode, I did:

```
try
{
   throw new Exception("test)";
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
#if DEBUG
            throw;
#else
Console.WriteLine("exception => " + ex.Message);
#endif
}
```

this works only on `throw`, on the else condition I get:

> The variable ex is declared but never used

Comment: just `throw ex;` ?

Comment: @Slai Please don't. That destroys the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Have two different catches, one in #if DEBUG and the other in the #else

Comment: You should avoid such difference behavior between DEBUG and RELEASE.

Comment: @Phil1970 don't worry, this is not for production, I'm just test this for learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#if DEBUG
catch(Exception)
{
     throw;
}
#else
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("exception => " + ex.Message);
}
#endif
```

Comment: thanks for this, but why the last catch seems commented?

Comment: I'm guessing you have `DEBUG` defined in your project, so only the `if` clause is compiled.

Comment: @Charanoglu the code that is not used is grayed out, and will switch if you change to Release mode.